# Django object query for counting different combinations of column counts

Tags: python, django, orm

I am trying to print in template the following structure (pseudocode)

```
class Car():
    field color
    field size
```

Where Column1 and Column2 represent different columns of same table (fields of object) and values are the possible values that this column can have.

How do I print this to template?

```
            red       orange        blue
small       123         4           45
regular     34          64          54
large       64          34          23
```

I know how to build tables, but the concept of django queries and as SQL to form some object I am not familiar with.

Comment: This is too abstract. Please show some models.

Comment: added a bit more realistic example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood well the question, I think you can do it with django group by approach

```
>>>>from your_app import models
>>>>from django.db.models import Count, Avg
>>>>combinations_dict_list = models.Car.objects.values('color', 'size').order_by().annotate(Count('color'), Count('size'))
>>>>combinations_dict_list
[{'color__count': 1, 'size__count': 1, 'color': 'red', 'size': 'small'}, 
 {'color__count': 2, 'size__count': 2, 'color': 'red', 'size': 'regular'}, 
 {'color__count': 3 'size__count': 3, 'color': 'red', 'size': 'large'},
...
]
```

You can get a dict with a count of the combination of your columns values. 
To render the result, you may create a dict with an color-size structure to easily iterate it in template

```
combinations_dict = {}
for comb in combinations_dict_list:
    if not combinations_dict.get(comb['color'], {}):
        combinations_dict[comb['color']] = {}
    if not combinations_dict[comb['color']].get(comb['size'], {}):
        combinations_dict[comb['color']][comb['size']] = {}
    combinations_dict[comb['color']][comb['size']] = comb['color__count']

colors = combinations_dict.keys()
sizes = combinations_dict[colors[0]].keys()
```

Template code

```
<table>
<tr><td>/td>
{% for color size in colors %}
    <td class="color_header">{{ combinations_dict.color.size}}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for size in sizes %}
    <tr>
        <td class="size_header">{{ size }}</td>
        {% for color, sizes  in combinations_dict.items %}
            {% for curr_size, val in sizes.items %}
                {% if size == curr_size %}
            <td class="value">{{ val}}</td>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: How do I iterate the results in template?

Comment: <td class="value">{{ combinations_dict.color.size}}</td>

 is not working somehow

Answer (score 0):

no direct way on database, what you should do is:
1. select count(1) count, size, color from car group by size, color
 will return something like
count size color
2     small  red
4     small  orange

2. render the result by size/color